# Extract Google Search Results with titles

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to ask how to extract text and urls from google search results as the same as is in google .
I have only this code but i do not know how make vb.net regex.
Everything what i need only to know how to extract text and urls.
Or you can suggest other regex code but to do that for the same as in the examples.

Example:

[image]

Text - `<h3 class="r"><a href="http://www..com/"><b>Welcome to dog training courses</b></a>`

Url - `<a href="http://..com/">Any link</a>`

example:

Text - `Welcome to dog training courses`
Url -  `www.dogtraining.com`

Text - `Welcome to Learning About Dogs`
Url -  `www.learningaboutdogs.com`

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        Dim wc As New WebClient
        Dim source As String = wc.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/search?&q=" + TextBox1.Text)
        Dim m1 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(source, "", RegexOptions.Singleline + RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        For Each m As Match In m1
            Dim value As String = m.Groups(0).Value


            If Not value.Contains("google") Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(value)
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: As an offside- If you are using this in any application - it is illegal to do this according to google's Terms of Service - http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/policies/terms/regional.html

Comment: Ok then suggest some cool that is legal example how to do this ;)

Comment: You can use Bing API for searching web. Check this article - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43419/Basics-of-Bing-Search-API-using-NET